# Can I change ID Token's expiry time for Firebase Auth Rest API?

Tags: firebase-authentication

I’m using a firebase auth rest api, and want to make sure my auto login system is working correctly after the ID token has expired. For that, I need to shorten the expiry time of ID Token from 3600 to something like 100. Is it possible to change expiry time of ID token for firebase auth rest api?

Comment: No you can't customize the expiration time.

Comment: I understand. Are there any ways to check if the auto login system like refreshing id token is working correctly except waiting 3600 second?